# Changing CRS crashes QGIS every time

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

When I open QGIS, and use the tools, setting -> project properties, QGIS will crash.

When I also use the setting -> option -> CRS , Select new CRS also causes a crash.

It looks like couldn't use the Coordinate Reference System Selector.

Can I fix it by myself?

Comment: Which version are you using. I remember this bug but it should be fixed.

Comment: What is the nature of your data? A properly formed shapefile? A kml?   If .shp , does it have a .prj file?

Comment: 1. 1.7.4
2. just open any file or none file , it always crash when I use CRS .

Comment: 1.8.0 on Mac OS 10.6.8 does almost the same thing: it doesn't crash when I change CRS from WGS84 (my source data) to UTM 18, but when saved that way it crashes on reloading project. Properly formed shapefiles with all aux files.

Comment: A problem like this ought to be sent as a bug report to the QGIS team, but all I can find are mailing lists for those involved in development. Is there a bug report link?